# How to Select Max Value From a View PosgreSQL

Tags: sql, view

I am new at SQL and I am trying to select a max value from a view. The database is of movies and actors, and the nested query part works. I am trying to find the actor that has the most co-actors, so the first thing I did was calculate the number of co-actors for each actor. Now I would like to select the value with the highest co-actors and return the number and the name of the actor. Please find below the attempted code:

```
CREATE VIEW actorview AS 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A2.name) AS Count, A.name AS Name
        FROM actors A, actors A2 
        WHERE A2.mid =A.mid
        GROUP BY A.name;
    
SELECT Name, MAX(Count) FROM actorview;
```

actors table

```
CREATE TABLE actors (mid integer NOT NULL, name varchar, cast_position integer, PRIMARY KEY (mid, name), 
                     FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES movies(mid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Edit:
In the above table mid (movie ID) represents the Movies an actor has been in, any actor that shares the same mid as another was in a movie with that actor. The view works for finding the number of co-actors every actor has, now I just need to select from that list the actor that has the most co-actors.

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and output data?

Comment: absolutely, np at all!

Comment: A good people already post an answer . Please look into the answer if its ok with you. If not then you should provide more input data. Because there have no indication how you found the sample output with your sample data.

Comment: If your problem has not been resolved please share table structure of Actors.

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Those are two very different database products

Comment: All actors have an equal number of co-actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function rank as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select a.name, count(distinct a2.name) as co_actors,
       Rank() over (order by count(distinct a2.name) desc ) as rn
  From actors a join actors c
    On a.mid = a2.mid and a.name <> a2.name
 Group by a.name) t
 Where rn = 1
```